# Spring MVC: Date is not displayed in the correct json format

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, backend

I have a field of type String, dateofbirth. This is entered as `dd/mm/yyyy` and then parse in `yyyy-mm-dd` (for saving in db).

When I check the GET API to view customers in the db via Postman I get that only the dateofbirth field is not saved in the correct json, because it is saved as below (ie without the " ").

```
"Codeperson": "BNCLSN43B12F205R",            
"Surname": "Bianchi",           
"Name": "Alessandro",       
"Dateofbirth": 1943-03-16
```

Obviously when I create a new customer, the date is entered in the Json format and saved correctly in the db. The problem I am experiencing is only in the GET.

DAO:

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> readViewListCustomerJson() {
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT * FROM cliente");



public boolean saveCustomer(Customer customer) {
    boolean status=false;
    try {
    jdbcTemplate.update("insert into cliente(codeperson, surname, name, dateofbirth) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", customer.getCodeperson(), customer.getSurname(), customer.getName(), customer.getDateofbirth());
    status=true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return status;
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value  = {"/customers-list"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
    public String ViewListCustomer() {
        return JSONArray.toJSONString(customerDao.readViewListCustomerJson());
    }



@RequestMapping(value = "/save-customer", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public boolean createCust(@RequestBody Customer customer) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy"); //Format for input
    java.util.Date dn = dateParser.parse(customer.getDateofbirth()); //Parsing the date
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd"); //Format for output
    customer.setDateofbirth(dateFormatter.format(dn)); //Printing the date
    return customerDao.saveCustomer(customer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add Annotation on date field in Customer Class in which format you want to get :

like that

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `spring.mvc.format.date=dd/MM/yyyy` in the `application.properties` of [Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#spring.mvc.format.date).

But you REST mappings look a bit strange, why are you returning a `List<Map<String, Object>`. This is very unspecific or generic. Why not returning a `List<Customer>` or a similar DTO for a customer. The JDBCTemplate should also support the return of real POJOs.

When using a real POJO you have also the possibility add a `@JsonFormat` annotation, e.g.:

```java
(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
```